# How to simulate a search in LinkedIn?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events, linkedin-api

I'm trying to simulate a search in Linkedin.com in Javascript console (I need to do it in Javascript, for a chrome extension development... not in Phantom, Selenium or other browser-simulation environments).

If I do this:

```
document.querySelector(".search-global-typeahead__input").dispatchEvent(new Event('focus', { bubbles: true }))
```

it seems it changes like the cursor was on it (because it triggers something in CSS behaviors and the field growths).

But I can't get to type something in the input field. My tries:

```
document.querySelector(".search-global-typeahead__input").dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress',{'key':'a'}));
document.querySelector(".search-global-typeahead__input").dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'key':'a'}));
document.querySelector(".search-global-typeahead__input").dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
document.querySelector(".search-global-typeahead__input").dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
...
```

I can use a simple "value":

```
document.querySelector(".search-global-typeahead__input").value = "Peter"
```

but then how can I trigger the search? I tried with keydowns and others ...

Any idea?